# Using Azure.Security.KeyVault to retrieve certificate (PFXcontent) via SecretId / SecretIdentifier instead of Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

Just wondering how you would achieve the same using the new `Azure.Security.KeyVault` libraries:

1. `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/security.keyvault.certificates-readme?view=azure-dotnet

1. `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/security.keyvault.secrets-readme?view=azure-dotnet#retrieve-a-secret

Particularly with regards to getting the PFX content from the certificate SecretId. The new libraries don't seem to offer a way to get the Secret by SecretId or SecretIdentifier, only by name.

With the aim of matching what would have previously been done like this:

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

CertificateBundle certificateBundle = await keyVaultClient.GetCertificateAsync(certificateIdentifier);

SecretBundle certificateWithPrivateKey = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(certificateBundle.SecretIdentifier.Identifier);

byte[] certificateWithPrivateKeyDecoded = Convert.FromBase64String(certificateWithPrivateKey.Value);

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateWithPrivateKeyDecoded, (string)null);

return certificate;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the method does not offer a way to get the Secret by SecretIdentifier, but it has a parameter `version`, see [`SecretClient.GetSecret(String, String, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.getsecret?view=azure-dotnet).

In your case, if you have the `certificateIdentifier`, the `secret name` and `version` are included, they are the same as the certificate, just pass them to the method.

[image]

```
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret("secret-name","secret-version");
```